# currency with comma as a seperator not dot in access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am designing dataentry form and I am preparing tables. later I want to get report according to my data.
in the table one field is for amount of fee , it should be at most 8 digits. without decimal . (this amount can be in 3 currency EUR, USD, pound so I have another field with combo box for it)

what I did is, I chose currency as a data type and I chose standard as a format ( I dont want to see any $ or eruo sign as I said I have another field to define it thats why I chose standard) and changed decimal to 0 ( I dont have any decimal) and limited input mask to 9999999.
I want to have , (comma) as a seperator not (.)dot . how should I change dot to comma ?
I want to see 4,300 not 4.300

Go to the top of the pageReport Post

Comment: The decimal separator is determined by your Windows settings. There is no simple way to alter that in your report.

Comment: in Excel we can change dot to comma . if I open option there is possibilty to change it. but in access i couldnt find anything.

Comment: Is it the decimal or the thousand separator?

Comment: thousand seperator

Answer (score 0):

If you environment doesn't change too much, you may get away with:

```
Amount = 4300
CommaSeparatedAmount = Replace(Format(Amount, "#,##0"), ".", ",")

' Returns 4,300
```